# How to change the sort order for letter groups

Tags: glossaries, sorting

I've used `makeindex` and the `glossaries` package to create a glossary, but I'd like to change the sort order for one of the "letter groups".

Basically, I have a set of entries that begin with a letter that isn't included in the default letter groups [A-Z]. All entries that begin with this letter are currently sorted under the "symbols" group. It was easy to change the name of the "symbols" group label to display the missing letter, but I would like this letter to be sorted after the "m" letter group rather than before the "a" letter group.

Is there an easy way to change the sort order for letter groups? I've been reading through the documentation, but I haven't found anything so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! I *think* you need `xindy`. If I remember correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen a lot of people talk about using xindy and if I had more time I would look into that solution. Unfortunately, I have several complex glossaries and I'm on a very tight deadline. I either need to find a quick way to adjust the sort order with makeindex or I'll just have to use a glossary style that doesn't display the letter groups and adjust what's listed in the sort id to get these 10 words listed before the /n/ entries. Since I don't need to "add" a letter group, I'm hoping there's a simple way to just change the sort order for a letter group.

Comment: what about `\index{mzzzmyword@myword}`

Comment: Right. I know that would place these ten entries before the n-entries. But I don't think that gives me a letter in the hyperlinked navigation bar at the beginning of the glossary... If I can, I'd like to have these ten entries be sorted before the n-entries and also have a letter appear in the navigation bar that would link to the beginning of this group of entries.

Comment: The way I currently have it, these entries are sorted under the "symbols" letter group and the "symbols" header label has been changed to print the first letter of these entries rather than "symbols". Now, if it's possible, I'm just trying to find a way to have the "symbols" group ( both the header label in the navigation bar and the entries) be sorted after the M group.

Comment: 1) you can edit your file by hand after runing makeindex or 2) post a MWE and we'll see

Comment: If your under a tight deadline and you don't have thousands of terms, your `\newglossaryentry{}` definition can be modified to include a `sort={}` definition that you could use to simulate your phonetic or pseudo-alphabetic ordering thus you can simulate where you want symbols such as greek characters to appear.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution (trick, one can do better)

### [image]

We define new entry (M-N, for example)

```
\newglossaryentry{mn}{%
name={\\[.5ex]\glsnavhypertarget{M-N}{M-N}\\[.5ex]}, 
description={\nopostdesc},sort=mzz}
```

here we should adjust vertical spaceing to look like group's heading. and `sort=mzz` to be after M group

Now specific entries are defined as sub-entries of (M-N)

```
\newglossaryentry{bal}{%
name={\hspace{-1em}$\beta$}, text={$\beta$},
description={algebra2},sort=mzzb, parent=mn}
```

horizontal space adjusted by `hspace{-1em}`

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[style=treehypergroup]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{mn}{%
name={\\[.5ex]\glsnavhypertarget{M-N}{M-N}\\[.5ex]}, 
description={\nopostdesc},sort=mzz}

\newglossaryentry{bla}{%
name=math,
description={algebra1}}

\newglossaryentry{bal}{%
name={\hspace{-1em}$\beta$}, text={$\beta$},
description={algebra2},sort=mzzb, parent=mn}

\newglossaryentry{bbla}{%
name={\hspace{-1em}$\alpha$},text={$\alpha$},
description={algebra3},sort=mzza, parent=mn}

\newglossaryentry{foo}{%
name=theory,
description={algebra4}}

\newglossaryentry{bar}{%
name=sciences,
description={algebra5}}


\newglossaryentry{lipsum}{%
name={\hspace{-1em}$\gamma$}, text={$\gamma$},
description={algebra6},sort=mzzg, parent=mn}

\newglossaryentry{tex}{%
name=TeX,
description={algebra7}}


\begin{document}

bla bla bla bla \gls{tex}
bla bla bla bla \gls{bar}
bla bla bla bla \gls{foo}
bla bla bla bla \gls{lipsum}
bla bla bla bla \gls{bla}
bla bla bla bla \gls{bbla}
bla bla bla bla \gls{bal}


\printglossaries 
\end{document}
```